GitPython get list of all commits from HEAD to Previous HEAD
I am using GitPython module to get the list of all commits from HEAD to Previous HEAD
Current HEAD  --> Changes I made recently
Previous HEAD --> When I cloned the repo
So far, I tried the following and able to get the last commit
import git
from git import repo

repo = git.Repo(".")

commits = repo.iter_commits('main^..main')

for commit in commits:
    for file in commit.stats.files:
        print(file)

However, I would like to get all the commits from Current HEAD to Previous HEAD
